# How to use PGPASSFILE environment variable?

Tags: postgresql

I am using `areca` backup program and I wrote a script in it to backup postgre database.
I want to get password via `pgpass.conf` file but I can't give it's path to script.
How can I use `PGPASSFILE` ?
This is my script (; is separator) :

```
-U;postgres;-w;-F;custom;-b;-f;D:\satraAutoBackup\Daily\Saturday\postgresql\geoMolkBackup;geoMolkPortal2
```

Comment: You can set the path of `pgpass.conf` using `PGPASSFILE` environement variable and remove the `-w` parameter

Answer (score 17):

1. Create .pgpass file with content

   > host:5432:somedb:someuser:somepass
2. set the permissions using command

   > sudo chmod 600 .pgpass
3. Set the file owner as the same user using which you logged in :

   > sudo chown login_username:login_username .pgpass
4. Set PGPASSFILE environment variable :

   > export PGPASSFILE='/home/user/.pgpass'

Now check by connecting to database (remove -w) :

> psql -h host -U someuser somedb

It will not prompt for password and logged in to postgresql.

Comment: I think creating the `PGPASSFILE` env is not mandatory as `~/.pgpass` is the default location of pgpass file.

Comment: For pg_dump it is the same, so instead of psql it is pg_dump -h host -U someuser somedb

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by setting the environment variable `PGPASSFILE` to the path of `pgpass.conf` and by removing the `-w` parameter.
eg.:`export PGPASSFILE="/path/to/pgpass.conf"`

PS: Make sure to set the `pgpass.conf` in a secure place and locking it using NTFS permission for example.

A use case here on this [wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Windows)